# Display an armature with one root bone

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, import

I have a .bvh file which has only one root bone, and when I import it through blender it doesn't appear. I don't know how I can make it appear so that I can see the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the animation uses so much space, that it doesn't appear anywhere near the center. You could scale the armature and its animation while importing

[image]

or use the Graph Editor, which is more flexible.

[image]

You can use the **Graph Editor** to move <kbd>G</kbd> and  scale <kbd>S</kbd> the F-Curves accordingly. Select the Armature ("bag") in the **Outliner**, switch to **Pose Mode**, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select the bone and switch a window to **Graph Editor**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! could you please tell me a detailed steps as I'm new to blender? After importing what should I do?

Comment: Thanks, I've done this, but I still can't see the bone armature, its still like a little dot. I want to know how to see the bone as in your screenshot shown in your answer.

Comment: could you please have a look at this question http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16633/combine-two-bvh-files-with-their-animation-in-one-bvh-file?noredirect=1#comment23738_16633

Comment: link updated [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04CY3llUnhmRmFabU0/view?usp=sharing)